# Counting a number in a list using pthreads.. C

Tags: c, pthreads

I am having trouble getting using pthreads to count the number of 3's in a list. Using a serial version of my code works fine but trying to use pthread_create is giving me trouble. Currently the problem is that count3s_thread_2(int id) is not giving me the same value as the serial version.
What do I need to change?
P.S., sorry for the mess. I am new to programming in C.

```
// Declares some global variables we will use throughout the
// program with all versions.
#define NUM_THREADS      4
int Length = 1000;
int array[1000];
int count;
long i;
pthread_mutex_t m;
pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

void create_list(int *array)
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   for (i = 0; i < Length; i++)
   {
      int r = rand();
      r = (r % 10) + 1;
      array[i] = r;
   }
}

void* count3s(void* threadid)
{
   // This is the function that counts the number of threes for
   // the first threaded version.
   //int i = (intptr_t)threadid;
   int i = (intptr_t)threadid;
   long tid = (long)threadid;
   int length_per_thread = Length / NUM_THREADS;
   long start = tid * (long)length_per_thread;

   for (i = start; i < start + length_per_thread; i++)
   {
      if (array[i] == 3)
      {
         count++;
      }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* count3s_v2(void* threadid)
{
   // This is the function that counts the number of threes for
   // the second threaded version.
   //int serial = count3s_serial();
   //printf("Number of threes: %d\n", serial);
   int i = (intptr_t)threadid;
   long tid = (long)threadid;
   int length_per_thread = Length / NUM_THREADS;
   long start = tid * (long)length_per_thread;

   for (i = start; i < start + length_per_thread; i++)
   {
      if (array[i] == 3)
      {
         pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
         count++;
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
      }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int count3s_serial()
{
   // This is the serial version of count3s. No threads are
   // created and run separately from other threads.
       count = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < Length; i++)
   {
      if (array[i] == 3)
      {
         count++;
      }
   }

   return count;
}

int count3s_thread(int id)
{
   clock_t begin, end;
   double time_spent;

   begin = clock();
   //pthread_attr_init();
   for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
   {
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, count3s, (void *)i);
   }
   //pthread_attr_destroy();
   end = clock();
   time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

   return count;
}

int count3s_thread_2(int id)
{
   clock_t begin, end;
   double time_spent;
   begin = clock();
   pthread_attr_init(&something);
   for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
   {
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, count3s_v2, (void *)i);
   }
   pthread_attr_destroy(&something);
   end = clock();
   time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

   return count;
   //printf("Thread Version 2: Number of threes = %d\nThread Version 2: Time Spent = %f\n", count, time_spent);
}

int main()
{
   create_list(array);
   clock_t begin, end;
   double time_spent;

   for (i = 0; i < Length; i++)
   {
      printf("%d\n", array[i]);
   }

   // Beginning of serial version. Timer begins, serial version
   // is ran and after it's done, the timer stops.
   begin = clock();
   int serial = count3s_serial();
   end = clock();

   time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   printf("Serial Version: Number of threes = %d\nSerial Version: Time Spent = %f\n", serial, time_spent);
   // End of serial version.
/*
*********************************************************************
*/
   // Beginning of first theaded version. Timer begins, first
   // threaded version is ran and after it's done, the timer stops.
   int the_thing = 0;
   count = 0;
   the_thing = count3s_thread(i);

   printf("Thread Version 1: Number of threes = %d\nThread Version 1: Time Spent = %f\n", the_thing, time_spent);
   // End of first threaded version.
/*
*********************************************************************
*/
   // Beginning of second theaded version. Timer begins, second
   // threaded version is ran and after it's done, the timer stops.
   int the_other_thing = 0;
   count = 0;
   the_other_thing = count3s_thread_2(i);

   printf("Thread Version 2: Number of threes = %d\nThread Version 2: Time Spent = %f\n", the_other_thing, time_spent);

   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Won't you potentially miss some if `Length` is not divisible by `NUM_THREADS`?

Comment: For debugging purposes, don't use srand, that way you should get the same result on each run. I'm wondering if length_per_thread is affected by integer division truncation.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, the definition of `NUM_THREADS` is not shown. If it is not an exact divisor of `Length` then it will result in `length_per_thread` for all the threads not adding up exactly to `Length`.

Comment: I added NUM_THREADS in sorry.

Comment: Which Length do you think should be divisible by NUM_THREADS? Sorry about the MCVE, new to posting and didn't want to leave anything important out. About NUM_THEADS being a divisor of Length, I have already thought of that and it should be okay.

Comment: Separately: consider using `atomic_int` for `count` instead of mutex locks, or using separate counters per thread and adding them together afterward.

Comment: The problem is that you spawn the threads but don't wait for them to finish before printing the result. Both thread versions have the same problem. And in the `count3s` function you have the extra problem of not protecting the increment with a mutex. For the first problem, use `pthread_join` to wait for the threads to exit or implement some other synchronisation for parent to know when the threads have completed their work.

Comment: I need to use mutex for this program and as crazy as this sounds the first threaded function needs to keep the race condition in there. I just need to figure out why the second threaded version is counting properly.

Comment: I told you. You are not waiting for the threads to complete. If the first thread version works for you (it doesn't for me) it is by chance and not because the code is correct.

Comment: Having looked at this and run it myself @AlanAu is completely correct.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm not being completely clear. The first is supposed to be wrong. The second is supposed to be the correct one. I am showing the differences between the correct and incorrect threaded versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you spawn the threads but don't wait for them to finish before printing the result. Both thread versions have the same problem. Use `pthread_join` to wait for the threads to exit or implement some other synchronisation for parent to know when the threads have completed their work.

For example, add the following block of code to the end of **both** `count3s_thread` and `count3s_thread_2`. It will wait for the threads to complete before printing the result. NOTE: You must add it to both functions (even though you are ok for the first one to have the wrong count). Otherwise when you run the second threading version the first set of threads are likely to still be executing and will mess up the global `count`.

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes perfect sense now and thanks for putting up with my very weird questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, mucked around with your code and got it to compile.  You aren’t waiting for your threads to return before you announce the result.  You need to `pthread_join()` each of your threads in `count3s_thread()` before it returns.